# Recommendation for resources about forecasting storm surge levels

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I have a number of concerns related to storm surge forecasting:

1. A large number of different models have been developed in order to forecast storm surge levels. I've read a lot of papers mentioning the different models they used and their results but I do not understand how these models have been applied. For example, I was reading about the implementation of the 2D hydrodynamic model but I seem to have a rather shallow understanding of what's happening. I would like to learn how to use these models to forecast storm surge levels myself so can someone guide me to resources/books that would help me to understand for myself the mathematics and the application of such models.
2. Another thing is if I want to study the storm surge levels for a particular cyclone I would need data to make a somewhat accurate forecasting model. So for forecasting storm surge levels what kind of data should I look for or what specific data variables would I definitely need?

Comment: [This might help you](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2225603219300207), as it discusses wave models.